# Pickers like a keyboard

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get a double picker to appear from the bottom of a screen when a certain button is selected? And is it possible to remove a value from a picker if it was already selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. I did that for an app just this summer. But you'll have to code the component yourself.

My suggestion is to create a class which has a `UIPickerView` member; this class, when instantiated and sent a message (like `-showInView:`), will make the view slide up. You'll need to have a delegate protocol for the class; it will probably make sense to have its delegate also implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to keep you updated but any chance could you explain that in simpler terms I'm relatively new to the iphone environment?